# How do I precompile assets for a PhoneGap app deployed to Heroku using Guard and Rake?

Tags: ruby, cordova, heroku, rake, guard

I would like to deploy the `www/` of my (PhoneGap) app to Heroku. I prefer HAML/SASS/CoffeeScript so I created a `Guardfile` to automatically generate HTML/CSS/JS and copy from `src/` to `www/`. I added `www/` to `.gitignore`. I would like to deploy to Heroku and have [`rake assets:precompile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-during-slug-compilation) generate the 'slug'/`www/` directory. I added a `Rakefile` according to the [Guard example](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Programmatic-use-of-guard)

```
require 'guard'

namespace :assets do
  desc "Precompile assets - build the whole app"
  task :precompile do
    Guard.run_all
  end
end
```

However when I try to run it locally, [`run_all`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/guard/Guard/Commander#run_all-instance_method) fails.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\TypeFunctions>bundle exec rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `run_all' for Guard:Module
C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/TypeFunctions/Rakefile:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can I fix this? (Or is there a better way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add

```
require 'guard/commander'
```

([Wiki Source](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Use-Guard-programmatically-cookbook#use-guard-programmatically-in-a-rake-or-capistrano-task))

and

```
Guard.setup
```

despite [the wiki](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Programmatic-use-of-guard) explicitly saying `# You can omit the call to Guard.setup, Guard.run_all will call Guard.setup under the hood if Guard has not been setuped yet`.

And I seem to definitely need `bundle exec...`.

Comment: Sorry about that. Guard needs an overhaul first. And tests to make sure that is never broken again.

Comment: Do open issues in GitHub for things like this - you'll not only get a response much faster, but often there will be a quickfix release with workarounds to help others. "Squeaky wheel gets the oil", etc...